# jenkins v1.537 email can not be sent to a 'group' email address - group email address derived in Distribution List Manager

Tags: jenkins

Performing post-build step
Checking if email needs to be generated
Email was triggered for: Success
Sending email for trigger: Success
Overriding default server settings, creating our own session
messageContentType = text/html; charset=UTF-8
Request made to attach build log
Adding recipients from recipient list
Adding developers
Successfully created MimeMessage
Sending email to: DL-eBayEnt-Build_Engineering@corp.ebay.com
[Current build status] check if current [SUCCESS] is worse or equals then [SUCCESS] and better or equals then [SUCCESS]
[Boolean condition] checking [false] against [^(1|y|yes|t|true|on|run)$] (origin token: ${ENV,var="NEXUS_RELEASE_COND"})
[Boolean condition] checking [false] against [^(1|y|yes|t|true|on|run)$] (origin token: ${ENV,var="IS_NEXUS_RELEASE"})
Run condition [And] preventing perform for step [Builder to mark whether executed]
Finished: SUCCESS

Comment: Sorry to all - above is the Jenkins output indicating success to email DL group but group does not receive email.

Comment: Closing my question / issue = it wasa network and DL manager issue of "outside accessibility" options not beign set. pELASE CLOSE THIS QUESTION / ISSUE

Comment: Can't you just delete the question?